# Выбор обфускатора для JAVA

Tags: защита, java, обфускация

Посоветуйте обфускатор, который **может**:

1. переименовывать файлы
2. перераспределять их по другим пакетам
3. И желательно что бы некоторые файлы можно было оставить неизменяемыми

*Пример того, как мы хотели бы:*

```
    package ru.game.name.pack1;

    import java.util.random;

    public class Class2 extends Class1
    { 
        private static int myInt1; 
        private static int myInt2 = 2 * myInt1;

    public Class1(int par1)
    {
        myInt1 = par1;
    }

    /*Дальше еще какой-то код... */
    }
```

*превращалось в*

```
package ru.game.name.A;

import java.util.random;

public class ab extends aa
{
    private static int ii;
    private static int ij = 2 * ii;

public ab(int par1)
{
    ii = par1;
}

/*Дальше еще какой-то код... */
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пожалуй, наиболее популярные:

1. [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).
2. [yGuard](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yguard_about.htm).

И небольшой [список](http://java-source.net/open-source/obfuscators).

Answer (score 5):

Возможно вам подойдет [Stringer Java Obfuscator](https://jfxstore.com/stringer)

> Stringer Java Obfuscator - это
> обфускатор, обеспечивающий высочайший
> уровень защиты Java-программ от
> реверс-инжиниринга и модификации. Для
> защиты приложений, вы можете
> использовать следующие функции:
> шифрование строк и проверка контекста
> вызова, защита от модификации и
> контроль целостности, оптимизация
> размера Java-приложений...

[Руководство по использованию Stringer Java Obfuscator](https://jfxstore.com/stringer/docs?language=ru)

Comment: 250$ за, кхм, нечто, умеющее, по большому счёту, лишь строковые литералы обрабатывать да `shrinking` делать (остальное там так себе, для галочки) — это немного странно, как мне кажется. Тем более, при наличии того же ProGuard'а, который на порядок функциональнее, да ещё и бесплатен.

Answer (score 3):

Поддержу [[[@falstaf](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf), для озвученных требований ProGuard более чем достаточно. Вот только толку от ProGuard'а никакого в плане реальной защиты от реверса, он изначально писался как оптимизатор (знаком с Эриком, создателем ProGuard'а), собственно им и остался. А вот на Stringer Java Obfuscator зря [[[@falstaf](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf) наезжает. Комбинация ProGuard + Stringer Java Obfuscator - это лучшее на рынке решение сейчас. А вот это "(остальное там так себе, для галочки)" вообще выбило из колеи, функционал Hide Access и Integrity Protection - самый сок, плюс использование InvokeDynamic, ни один декомпилятор пока несправляется. Ощущение, что [[[@falstaf](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf) даже не видел вживую продукт, но горазд обсуждать.