# Запретить просмотр содержимого Jar-файла архиватором

Tags: java, eclipse

Я создаю приложения для компьютеров в среде программирования Eclipse.

Можно ли создать такой Jar-файл, в котором нельзя просмотреть содержимое с помощью архиватора?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [обфускацией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Она позволяет запутать код, есть опция переименования class'ов. Jar - нужен всего лишь для удобного распространения пакетов библиотек и приложений. Он не задумался как средство защиты файлов от чтения.

Один из свободных обфускаторов для Java - [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net).
На Ru.SO есть вопрос про [java обфускаторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/277318/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-java).

Answer (score 5):

Нет, нельзя. Jar - это простой ZIP-архив, с нестандартным расширением. Опции "запрета просмотра содержимого" этот формат не имеет.

Comment: А если из Jar файла сделать Exe, то можно ли запретить просматривать этот Exe файл?

Comment: Exe - это всего лишь Загрузчик приложения на java, то есть jre все равно необходимо, соответственно zip и class никуда не денутся.